# FixedColumns extension of DataTables cause column duplicity

Tags: datatables

I am using jQuery plugin DataTables https://datatables.net/ with extension Fixed Columns https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/

this is my javascript code

```
var datatable;

        $(document).ready(function () {

            datatable = $('#data-table').DataTable({
                "scrollX": true,
                "scrollCollapse": true,
                "fixedColumns": {
                    "leftColumns": 3,
                    "rightColumns": 1
                },
                stateSave: true,
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "drawCallback": function () {
                    feather.replace();
                    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
                },
                "ajax":
                {
                    "url": "@Url.Action("GetDataTableData","General")",
                    "type": "POST"
                    },
                "columnDefs": [
                    {
                        "targets": 33,
                        "data": function (data) { return "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"edit(" + data[33] + ")\">Edit</a> <a href=\"#\" onclick=\"deleteProject(" + data[33] + ")\"><span color=\"red\" data-feather=\"x\"></span></a>" },
                    }
                ]
            });

        });
```

Because i have a lot of columns and `"scrollX"` property set to `true` i can see horizontal sidebar in my datatable.

This is result which can happen in two scenarios

[image]

**scenario 1 :** hiding columns (https://datatables.net/examples/api/show_hide.html)

```
column.visible( ! column.visible() );
```

and last fixed column is duplicated when there is no need for horizontal sidebar (because user hide most of the columns)

**scenario 2 :** resize bootstrap page width

```
$("#sidebar").removeClass("sidebar-hidden");
```

I have similar hiding effect as is described in this example https://codepen.io/Xeoncross/pen/zxyWeW

Because i am also using property `"stateSave": true` the duplicity remain even i refresh the page.

What is wrong here, how can i remove duplicity of the last action column ?

Fiddle example : https://jsfiddle.net/g7tdqm9h/32/

Comment: do you have demo codepen or fiddle, where we can see duplicity of last action column?

Comment: did you try `"scrollXInner": true` instead of  `"scrollX": true"` or by setting `fixedHeader: true`

Comment: @yash Yes i have fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/g7tdqm9h/28/ `scrollXInner` or `fixedHeader` does not help :/

Comment: @yash i edited column indexes a little https://jsfiddle.net/g7tdqm9h/32/ (column19 was missing)

Comment: Hi @Mufix, change `"scrollX": true" `  by ` "scrollXInner": true`, it will remove duplicate action column., `fixedHeader: true` also working for me.

Comment: @yash yes, but it will also disable the scrollbar :/ Maybe as a workaround, i can count number of columns displayed. And if there is small number of columns displayed, i will remove `scrollX` parameter and redraw table.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same thing, but then i check again i'm using DataTables bs4 (if you use the same), so i found the main problem. Link: https://datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/FixedColumns/examples/styling/bootstrap4.html , i forgot to add the CSS, i don't know if this works for you, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try This. It works for me

```
var empTable = $('#empList').DataTable( {
  sScrollX: "100%",
  sScrollXInner: "150%"        
});
```